# pcolormesh ticks center for each data point/tile

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, heatmap

I have some z=f(x,y) data that I would like to display in a heat map. So I am using `np.meshgrid` to create a (x,y)-grid and then call `pcolormesh`. However the ticks are not centered for each "tile" that correspond to a data point -- in the docs, I did not find any instructions on how to center the ticks for each tile so that I can immediately read off the corresponding value. Any ideas?

In the image attached for instance, it is not clear to which x-value the tick corresponds.

[image: Ticks]

Comment: Isn't the heat at `(0,0)` ranging **from** 0 **to** 1. So I would think the cell immediately right from the tick corresponds to the x-position of the tick?

Answer (score 6):

In a pcolormesh the grid is defined by the edge values. In the following example the value of 6 in the lower left corner is the value between 0 and 1 in each dimension. I think this is perfectly understandable to everyone.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)

x = np.arange(5)
y = np.arange(3)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = np.random.randint(1,9, size=(2,4))

plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z)

plt.show()
```

Now if you want to (only) have the ticks in the middle of the cell, you can set them as follows

```
plt.xticks(x[:-1]+0.5)
plt.yticks(y[:-1]+0.5)
```

[image]

If the lower left pixel actually does not correspond to the data between 0 and 1, but to the data **at** 0, the grid is *'wrong'*; a solution would be to fix it by translating it by half the pixel width.

```
plt.pcolormesh(X-0.5,Y-0.5,Z)
```

[image]

As above, the ticks could be adapted to show only certain numbers, using `plt.xticks`.

Comment: The "pixel width" is in general for equi-spaced data `(x[1] - x[0])/2`, correct?

Comment: No, the pixel width is just `(x[1] - x[0])`. In all of the above this is `1`.